# SharePoint Online / 365 - Parse .MSG file server-side without outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, outlook

I need to parse .msg files saved from Outlook, extract subject and attachments.

Is it possible to parse msg files without a 3rd party extension in a sandboxed solution?

The .msg files will be located in a document library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a .MSG file is complicated because you have to dissect a msg file generated by Outlook, and read the basic properties of the mail message, attachments and any msg attachments (these need to be handled differently).

These two links could be a good starting point for you:
http://pstsdknet.codeplex.com/discussions/273197
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C